# What could cause the error: "Fatal Error: Out of memory - aborting" from simply including a header file?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to create a brick breaker game using SDL2. Most of the code can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/Joe12o/5e643b952ac739dfd56d) aside from a couple header files that don't seem relevant. It compiles fine, but when running it it instantly stops with the error, "Fatal Error: Out of memory - aborting". The problem is fixed if I comment out the #include on lines 58, 59, and 62 and all references to them in that class, but that is not ideal.

Comment: can you post the code where the error(s) is occurring?

Comment: @bwegs In order to fix it I had to remove: #include <SDL2/SDL.h>, #include "ball.h", SDL_Rect getPaddleBounds();, Ball ball;, and SDL_Rect paddleBounds;. All of these can be found in level.h [here](https://gist.github.com/Joe12o/5e643b952ac739dfd56d#file-brickbreaker-cpp-L55). This is not a good fix though as I need to use these for the game.

Comment: You are not handling events properly here. You only poll once per frame with `if (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)` - you should use `while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))` to ensure you handle the full event queue.

Comment: @Zammalad Ok thanks for the info, but that's the last of my problems here. Any ideas on how to fix the memory issue?

Comment: @TheRuiner Are you able to post the full project so I can run locally?

Comment: @Zammalad Sure, here you go: https://github.com/Joe12o/Project

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure out the problem so here was my problem for anyone who has the same issue. I forgot to add #define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED to the file where I included the SDL header files.